# Bash bc and echo commands

Tags: macos, bash, echo, bc

I'm writing small geeklet for geektool, to alert me when sum of inactive and free RAM on my Mac will become slow. I'm not really good with bash, so I have a problem with final output (getting blank).
Here is code:

```
inMem=$(top -l 1|awk '/PhysMem/ {print $6}'|sed s/M//) | freeMem=$(top -l 1|awk '/PhysMem/ {print $10}'|sed s/M//) | totalMem=$inMem+$freeMem | bc | echo $totalMem
```

Also wonder if my issue is optimal or not.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is there no `free` command in OSX?

Comment: @SeanBright: there is not.

Comment: On OS X, you'd be better off querying `sysctl -a vm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if this could actually simplify your commands. I can't test it since I'm not on OSX but I hope it works.

```
read inMem freeMem totalMem < <(top -l 1 | awk '/PhysMem/ { i = $6; sub(/M/, "", i); f = $10; sub(/M/, "", f); printf("%d %d %d\n", i, f, i + f); exit; }')
echo "inMem: $inMem"
echo "freeMem: $freeMem"
echo "totalMem: $totalMem"
```

Comment: +1 for the general approach, although it could still be simplified a lot if you don't need to have the values in shell variables.

Comment: @tripleee My initial version of it was actually only the command itself without showing the value for `inMem` and `freeMem` but I can't generalize what the OP really wants.

Comment: Oh I mean simply `top -l 1 | awk '... END { print "inMem: " i; print "freeMem: " f; print "totalMem: " i+f }'`

Comment: Thanks a lot) echo commands just for testing, I need only totalMem value, due its show total memory which can be used.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of parsing `top`, use the `/proc/meminfo` file. For example, with:

```
$ head -2 /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        4061696 kB
MemFree:          335064 kB
```

you can see to total and free memory

Comment: OSX does not have procfs.

Answer (score -1):

[user000001 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18615348/2698019) is right, but then the question is "How to get `/proc/meminfo` output into variables?"

You can use this pure bash solution for parsing:

```
read -d '' _  memTotal _ _ memFree _ < <(head -2 /proc/meminfo)
```

Comment: The only gotcha here is that assuming that the positions map to the desired variables is unsafe without reading their names -- future kernels may reorder while adding new values.

Comment: OS X does not have /proc/meminfo